# Un-Check item in Choice field type (multi)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, choice-field

I am currently working on a project that has something like the following fields.

None
Fish
Steak
Vegan

None is checked by default. What I am looking to do is to un-check None when ever a different choice is selected.

Comment: Is this is a choice field with "Display Choices Using:" Checkboxes?  Would you like the option to select multiple choices?

Comment: This is choice field with allowing multiple selections

Comment: Could you take away the "None" option and leave all selections Blank until selected?  Or do you need it to start with "None"?

Comment: No, This list is actually for Documenting access, Required to document a no access item.

Comment: Ahh understood.  Could you make it a required field and leave the choices blank until someone selected one?  (Sorry if it seems like I am trying to work around your process haha not intentional)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi Select Choice field is rendered as a table with checkboxes and label for each choice. You should edit the New form and insert this JavaScript using Script editor or reference it through a js file

```
//Replace actual id of the table
      $('#<idofTable> input').each(function () {
            if ($(this).next().text() != "None") {
                $(this).change(function () {
                    if (this.checked) {
                        //Uncheck when some other choice is checked
                        $('#<idofTable>').find('span[title*="None"]').children('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
                    }
                    else if ($('#<idofTable> input:checked').length == 0) {
                        //Check None if nothing else is checked
                        $('#<idofTable>').find('span[title*="None"]').children('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: Could you explain this a little more #<idofTable> input I am not sure what to put here

Comment: You have to inspect element of the multi select choice field in newform.aspx in browser. Then find the id of the parent table which holds the checkboxes. Replace <idofTable> with that id